# How to calculate eigenvalues and matrix A from these:

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations

If I have matrix $A$ and I know eigenvectors $\mathbf v_1$ and $\mathbf v_2$:

[image: Matrix A and eigenvectors v1 and v2]

a) How can I calculate eigenvalues for vectors $\mathbf v_1$ and $\mathbf v_2$

b) How can I solve $a,b,c,d$

Can you give me steps what do calculate to get right answers?

Comment: Multiply the matrix and an eigenvector. What do you see?

Comment: I multiplied the matrix with eigenvector v1 and v2 i see linear equations the first two rows and third component is numeric. what then?

Comment: Effectively a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2510634/265466

Answer (score 0):

You know $A v_1 = \lambda_1 v_1$ and $Av_2 = \lambda_2 v_2$ where $\lambda_1$ is the eigenvalue corresponding to $v_1$ and $\lambda_2$ is the eigenvalue corresponding to $v_2$. Looking at the third component, you can calculate $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$.

Now you get a system of linear equations for $a,b,c,d$ which you can solve.

Comment: can you give me an example from my as i don't quite get it yet.

Comment: Can you calculate $Av_1$ and $Av_2$? Look at the third component. What does it mean for $v_1$ and $v_2$ to be eigenvectors?

Comment: Can't calculate it without he eigenvalue right? what do you mean by third component? v1 and v2 is eigenvectors from A and i am missing still v3. I am really confused..

Comment: You are given $A$ and $v_1$, although $A$ contains variables $a,b,c,d$ you can still calculate $Av_1$. You know that $v_1$ is an eigenvector of $A$, thus the third component of $Av_1$ has to be a multiple of the third component of $v_1$. Also the third column of $A$ does not contain any variables, so neither will the third component of $Av_1$.

Comment: Still not getting it and i don't know why because you explained it really good. Can you give me example with given A and v1 so i can get it? Av1 is the first column of the A? So should i multiply A*v1 or?

Comment: Yes $Av_1$ denotes the multiplication $A \cdot v_1$.

Comment: So if i multiply A⋅v1 and A*v2 i get some results with example:a+5b+168. what do i do with this matrix after this? Third component is numeric in both what does this mean?