# How to calculate $a,b,c,d$ given the eigenvectors

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations

> Given the matrix 
>   $$A=\begin{bmatrix}
>         a & b & 2 \\
>         c & d & 6 \\
>         3 & 4 & -3 
>         \end{bmatrix}$$
>   with  eigenvectors
>   $$v_1=\begin{bmatrix}
>         5 \\
>         1 \\
>         3 
>         \end{bmatrix}
> \quad\text{and}\quad v_2=\begin{bmatrix}
>         7 \\
>         4 \\
>         3 
>         \end{bmatrix}$$
>   find $a,b,c,d$.

After this i know i should compute $Av_1$ and $Av_2$.
$$Av_1=\begin{bmatrix}
        5a+b+6 \\
        5c+d+18 \\
        10
        \end{bmatrix}$$
So what next in order to find value for $a,b,c,d$?

Comment: What is the definition of an eigenvector? Write it out and you should see how to generate equations that need solved.

Comment: Effectively a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2510473/265466.

Answer (score 3):

$A*V_1 = \lambda*V_1$

$A*V_1$ is
\begin{bmatrix}
        5a+b+6 \\
        5c+d+18 \\
        10 \\
        \end{bmatrix}

$\lambda*V_1$ is
\begin{bmatrix}
        5*\lambda \\
        1*\lambda \\
        3*\lambda \\
        \end{bmatrix}
On equating, we see that $\lambda = \frac{10}{3}$

Similarly solve for other eigen value. Then with equations formed, get the desired values

Comment: So if i have $V_2$ as \begin{bmatrix}
        7a+4b+6 \\
        7c+4d+18 \\
        28\\
        \end{bmatrix} the first eigenvalue is $λ_1$=10/3 so  is the second $λ_1$=28/3 can you help me and can you show how i can solve the linear system(1) and (2) with respec to a,b,c and d?

Comment: Well, now you have 4 variables and 4 equations. It is solvable. Either use substitution method or matrix method

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Note that by the definitions of [eigenvalue and eigenvector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors),
$$\begin{bmatrix}
        5a+b+6 \\
        5c+d+18 \\
        10 
        \end{bmatrix}=Av_1=\lambda_1 v_1=\begin{bmatrix}
        5\lambda_1 \\
        \lambda_1 \\
        3\lambda_1 
        \end{bmatrix}$$ 
    and looking at the third component wefind that $10=3\lambda_1$, that is $\lambda_1=10/3$. Hence
$$\begin{cases}
5a+b+6=5\lambda_1 \\
5c+d+18=\lambda_1  \\
\end{cases}\implies \begin{cases}
5a+b=32/3 &\text{(1)}\\
5c+d=-44/3 &\text{(2)}\\
\end{cases}.$$
Now do the same thing with the other eigenvector $v_2$ and you will obtain another couple of equations (3) and (4). Finally solve the linear system of (1) and (3) with respect to $a$, $b$ and the linear system of (2) and (4) with respect to $c$, $d$.

Comment: So if i have $V_2$ as \begin{bmatrix}
        7a+4b+6 \\
        7c+4d+18 \\
        28\\
        \end{bmatrix} the first eigenvalue is $λ_1$=10/3 so  is the second $λ_1$=28/3 can you help me and can you show how i can solve the linear system(1) and (2) with respec to a,b,c and d?

Comment: \begin{bmatrix}
        5a+b=32/3 \\
        5c+d)-44/3 \\
        \end{bmatrix}

and

\begin{bmatrix}
        7a+4b=10/3 \\
        7c+4d=-26/3 \\
        \end{bmatrix}

Comment: Can you help me with solving linear system compinations (1) and (3) with respect a,b? And also (2) and (4) with respect c,d?

Comment: Make a try. Find $b$ from (1) and plug it into (3).

Comment: Is the b from (1) 11-5*a and then i add it to (3) i get 122/39 and this is value of b?

Comment: $b$ is not correct. $32/3$ is not $11$

Comment: Oh sorry i typed wrong so b from (1) is 32/3-5*a and this to (3) it gives 118/39. Is this correct?

Comment: Check again $7a+4b=10/3$. Is $10/3$ correct? You are near to the end. Revise your work and check your computations.

Comment: Yeah you are right i didn't use the eigenvector multiplation so its:\begin{bmatrix}
        7a+4b=70/3 \\
        7c+4d=-104/3 \\
        \end{bmatrix} and then the b from (1) to (3) gets b=58/39?